# SQL query to get start and end positions based on batch size

Tags: sql, t-sql, rownum

I have a table A with identity column as PK, along with other columns.  This table has like 10M records. Sample data in identify column is as below

```
ID
--
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Note: there is no 4.  it would have got delete.

i want to process them in batches and track if the processing is complete or not.  so i want to create another table with below structure

batch id, start Id, end Id

in that in want data like

```
batch id, start Id, end Id
1,1, 2  
2,3,5
3,6,7
4,8,9
5,10,10
```

This is considering batch size of 2.  Batch size is configurable.

What query should i write to form above table by querying table A.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And how is 6-8 in a batch size of "2"?

Comment: sorry typo, changed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and arithmetic:

```
select floor((seqnum + 1) / 2) as batch, min(id), max(id)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor((seqnum + 1) / 2)
```

Comment: thanks for the query. it is working as expected for batch size of 2.  but what shd i do to change the batch size a variable parameter.  like if i change the batch size to 3, what shd i do? thanks.

Comment: @user1447718: you can just replace the two occurences of `/ 2` with the batch size that you like.

Comment: This worked....select floor((seqnum + (n-1)) / n) as batch, min(id), max(id)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor((seqnum + (n-1)) / n)